# Get system information off a remote PC and write it to a local file (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

So im trying to write a script that collects system info off of a computer on the network, then writes the information collected to a HTML file in my C:\ drive. Here's what I have so far.

```
Invoke-Command -computername WIN-I9EKPIP774N -credential Administrator -ScriptBlock { 
$OS= (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption; 
$PK= powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey"; 
$MN= (Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem).Manufacturer;  
$SN= Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select SerialNumber; 
$CPU= Get-WMIObject win32_Processor | select name; 
$RAM= (systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim(); 
$GPU= Get-WmiObject win32_VideoController|select videoProcessor; Write-host "GPU: " 
    $Result= $GPU, $OS, $PK, $SN, $CPU, $RAM
        $Result|out-file C:/SYSINFO.HTML -computername DESKTOP-TA132FJ}
```

The command collects the information on the remote computer fine, but im having trouble sending it back to write the info to my local file. I added the machines to trustedhosts respectively, both by IP and hostname, but still cannot get it to connect back to my local machine and write to the file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you create a variable and store the invoke command in that variable, then pipe the variable to out-file, you get your results. Also, instead of using the computer name, I ended up adding the systems to the trusted host file by IP address. The resulting code looked like this.

```
$OVERALL= Invoke-Command -computername 172.16.50.50 -credential Administrator -ScriptBlock { 
$OS= (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption; 
$PK= powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey"; 
$MN= (Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem).Manufacturer;  
$SN= Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select SerialNumber; 
$CPU= Get-WMIObject win32_Processor | select name; 
$RAM= (systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim(); 
$GPU= Get-WmiObject win32_VideoController|select videoProcessor;
$Result= $GPU, $OS, $PK, $SN, $CPU, $RAM;
$Result};
$OVERALL| Out-file C:\SYSINFO.HTML
```

This successfully sent a request for sys information from the localhost to a remote machine, and wrote the sys information of the remote host to a html file on the localhost. Cool learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -computername blah -ScriptBlock { (do stuff) | out-file targetfile.txt }
```

Because the `out-file` is in the script block, it's executed on the remote computer. The easiest fix is to move that so it's outside the script block, so it's more like:

```
Invoke-Command -computername blah -ScriptBlock { (do stuff) } | out-file targetfile.txt
```

This way, the output will be piped through `out-file` on the local computer, and you don't need to try and work out permissions in the reverse direction.

Comment: I did give that a shot, and it did not write to the file. I also tried     write-host $Result}| out-file C:\SYSINFO.html with no luck as well

Comment: Maybe it's a problem writing to the root of C:\ -- are you able to write the file to your profile's desktop or documents folder?

Comment: I got it working by storing the invoke command as a variable then piping the variable to out-file! Thanks a bunch for your effort though buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like everything that you put i side the scriptblock, will happen at the remote computer, anything outsider will run on your local computer.

With this in mind, if you write to a file in the SB, it will be written to disk on the remote. Another feature of PS is that things (in this case the Invoke-Command) almost always returns things, so if you remove everything after `$Result`, including `|`, the array `$Result` will be returned.

Thus you can put it a variabler and then write it to file.

```
$Computer = "WIN-I9EKPIP774N"
$stuff = @{ win32_operatingsystem = "Version"
SoftwareLicensingService = "OA3xOriginalProductKey"
win32_ComputerSystem = "Manufacturer"
win32_bios = "SerialNumber"
win32_Processor = "Name"
Win32_PhysicalMemory = "Capacity"
win32_VideoController = "videoProcessor"
}

$SysInfo = [pscustomobject]::new()
$stuff.Keys | foreach { $SysInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value ( Get-CimInstance -ClassName $_ -ComputerName $Computer )."$( $stuff.$_ )" }

$SysInfo | Out-File C:\SYSINFO.HTML
```

**Edit**
I realized I made some errors in my codesuggestion, so rewrote and modified it to make it simpler to handle.
`$stuff` contains the classes you want to get info from, and the property from that class.
The RAM will be a list of capacities for each memorycard if there are more than one.